# If hashtable maps two keys to same value in a table, how will I get back my key

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, hashtable

Can someone explain this to me, how will I get back my key if hashtable maps two keys to same value. Although, there is a linked list storing two sequential values, who decides which key to spit out when a common value is used to get the key/element. Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Wait, so you're trying to use a value to find keys, not the other way around?

Comment: JJohusman, If a hash table has a function that maps a huge data, while it is doing it , if it maps two different keys to same value. Then the values are stored in bucked in sequential manner using linked list. How will I get back my Key if there are two keys for a single hash value.

Comment: You should edit the question to make clear you're talking about the key's hash value, not about the object the key is associated with.

Answer (score 5):

Two keys mapping to the same hash value is called a collision. Any collection that uses hashing to store and lookup data must be able to handle collisions. This may be done, for example, with a linked list for each hash that contains multiple items (each collision).

Such a collection also stores the actual key. So if it finds a collision, it can still scan through those items to find the exact match. It just isn't as fast as when there is no collision because of the extra scan.

Comment: Can I take Jonathan's answer as correct one or should I wait for better explanation.

Comment: @delnan: I also think this interpretation is what the OP meant to ask.  It makes more sense than reading "value" as the mapped-to value, but we really need clarification.  Also notice the OP uses "key", "value", and "element", so element could be what you're calling value and value could be the hash.

Comment: @Fred Yes, the OP was not entirely clear, in part due to phrasing. It could definitely be made more clear, but sometimes you just need to try and read between the lines.

Comment: @ranjanarr The problem is that there is some question about exactly what you were asking. If my reply answers your question, then my interpretation must've been correct.

Comment: Even if element = value and value = hash value, that still doesn't explain why he wants to "get back my key". Color me confused.

Comment: @Jonathan Oh, I have complete respect for the difficulty of the English language for non-native speakers; that's not what I'm getting at, and I wasn't trying to be rude to him. I was just questioning the reasoning in these comments, but since the OP seems satisfied, I guess it's true :)

Comment: @johusman: I didn't mean to suggest you were being rude. Only that perhaps the specific words should be taken with a grain of salt. Looking at some of the newer comments from the OP, they seem to confirm he wanted to know how it could get a unique value back when there was a collision with the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Hashtables are not designed to return the key by using the stored value, but rather the other way around. If you, however, need such functionality - having a bidirectional relation key <-> value - then you have various options:

- Use two hashtables, one that stores key -> value, one that stores the other part of the relation - value -> key
- Use a BiDirectional hashtable implementation (Google has one spec'd [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.java?r=2)) which supports this by doing the same thing internally

Answer (score 0):

a) You are assuming a particular implementation of your hashtable
b) This is very much implementation dependent.

Hashtables are for mapping keys -> values. The inverse mapping may not be possible, and as you have identified may not be well behaved.

Answer (score 0):

**You**(or whoever creates the hashtable implementation) decides what to do when you insert a key that already exists.

The 2 common approaces are:

- Fail. Don't insert the new key/value, but indicate that the key already exists.
- Replace the existing key/value and return the old key/value pair.

A 3. option, which I havn't at least seen much in any C/C++ hashtable implementation:

- Retain the original key, but update/replace the new value for this key